# Superset API not working (The CSRF session token is missing.)

Tags: python, apache-superset

Im using a python docker container to access a container with superset in it.  I wrote a class that access the superset container.  Currently, I have a few requests that work already (such as getting the csrf token and authentication token), however, trying few other requests dont work.

Im using this to create the superset container (windows)

```
git checkout 3.0.0
set TAG=3.0.0
docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

and here is my class

```
class Superset:
    """Class for Superset"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.port = os.environ["SUPERSET_PORT"]
        self.host = os.environ["SUPERSET_HOST"]
        self.username = os.environ["SUPERSET_USERNAME"]
        self.password = os.environ["SUPERSET_PASSWORD"]
        self.url = f"http://{self.host}:{self.port}"
        (
            self.auth_token,
            self.refresh_token,
        ) = self.__get_superset_access_and_refresh_tokens()
        self.csrf_token = self.__set_csrf_token()

    def __set_csrf_token(self):
        """Get token to auth"""
        security_url = f"{self.url}/api/v1/security/csrf_token/"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.auth_token}",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
        }
        response = self.session.get(security_url, headers=headers)

        return str(response.json()["result"])

    def __get_superset_access_and_refresh_tokens(self):
        """Authenticate and get access token"""
        access_token_url = f"{self.url}/api/v1/security/login"

        json_headers = {
            "username": self.username,
            "password": self.password,
            "provider": "db",
            "refresh": True,
        }

        response = self.session.post(access_token_url, json=json_headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            logging.info("Successfully connected to superset")
        else:
            raise ConnectionError(
                f"Failed to authenticate with Superset API. Status code: {response.status_code}"
            )
        access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
        refresh_token = response.json()["refresh_token"]

        return access_token, refresh_token

    def star_things(self):
        """Imports dashboard from zipfile"""
        star_url = f"{self.url}/api/v1/dashboard/10/favorites/"

        # Define your custom headers
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.auth_token}",
            "X-CSRFToken": self.csrf_token,
            "Referer": f"{self.url}/api/v1/security/csrf_token/",
        }

        response = self.session.post(star_url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Favorited something")

        print(response.status_code)

    def get_dashboards(self):
        """Get all dashboard json"""
        dashboard_url = f"{self.url}/api/v1/dashboard/"
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.auth_token}",
            "X-CSRFToken": self.csrf_token,
        }

        response = self.session.get(dashboard_url, headers=headers)

        return response.json()
```

The method get_dashboards() works as well as __get_superset_access_and_refresh_tokens and __set_csrf_token, however, the method star_things() does not work.  When I try star_things() method request, I get

```
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 2023-10-31 02:10:18,849:INFO:flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Refresh CSRF token error
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token())
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.")
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     rv = self.preprocess_request()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2313, in preprocess_request
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 229, in csrf_protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     self.protect()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 264, in protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     self._error_response(e.args[0])
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 307, in _error_response
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     raise CSRFError(reason)
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 2023-10-31 02:10:18,849:WARNING:superset.views.base:Refresh CSRF token error
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token())
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.")
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     rv = self.preprocess_request()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2313, in preprocess_request
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 229, in csrf_protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     self.protect()
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 264, in protect
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     self._error_response(e.args[0])
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 307, in _error_response
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          |     raise CSRFError(reason)
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 172.23.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2023:02:10:18 +0000] "POST /api/v1/dashboard/10/favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 302 201 "http://host.docker.internal:8088/api/v1/security/csrf_token/" "python-requests/2.31.0"
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'pyhive.sqlalchemy_trino.TrinoDialect'>: No module named 'google'
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 2023-10-31 02:10:18,893:WARNING:superset.db_engine_specs:Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'pyhive.sqlalchemy_trino.TrinoDialect'>: No module named 'google'
2023-10-30 20:10:18 superset_app          | 172.23.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2023:02:10:18 +0000] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51503 "http://host.docker.internal:8088/api/v1/security/csrf_token/" "python-requests/2.31.0"
```

What I dont get is I am passing the csrf token in the post request, as well as using it in the same session, so not sure why I am having issues

Ive tried multiple configurations, nothing has worked to get past the csrf errors